# How to set up pound for nodejs http server?

Tags: node.js, linux, pound

There are currently several Raspberry-Pi on my LAN. Pound is on one of them, to redirect traffic to the others. There is no problem with Apache HTTP servers, but recently I am trying out NodeJS, the server is not reachable from the Internet via Pound. Typing LAN_IP:3000 will show the hello-world message, but URL:3000 will not. A message "Cannot GET /path" is shown.

Below is the service section of pound.cfg

```
Service
    HeadRequire "Host:.*my.domain.tld.*"
    BackEnd
            Address 192.168.1.2
            Port    3000
    End
```

End

Is it NodeJS HTTP works differently from Apache HTTP?
(The NodeJS HTTP is triggered by express framework)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked in your application if your /path route is returning 404??

Comment: @FernandoZamperin Thanks for your comment. I have confirmed it is really the path problem. Dummy question LOL